# Representation of Real Number as infinte Product $\prod(1\pm2^{-k})$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, real-numbers

In some paper describing a variant of CORDIC, I found basically the claim that every real number $x$ in some interval $[u,v]$ with $u\approx0.2887$ and $v\approx2.384$, can be represented as:

$$
x = \prod_{k=1}^\infty (1\pm2^{-k}) \tag1
$$
As I found, the algorithm isn't working properly, and the cause could be that the paper is wrong, which I am trying to understand. (And maybe also to fix. For my purpose it's sufficient when $v/u\geqslant2$.)

To show that a representation like $(1)$ does not exist for a full interval containing $1$, I startet like this:

---

For some sequence $a=\{a_k\}_{k=1}^\infty, a_k\in\{-1,+1\}$, let

$$
f(a,n) := \prod_{k=n}^\infty (1+a_k 2^{-k}) \tag2
$$
We can introduce a complete order on all possible sequences by means of:

- Let $a > b$ if there is some index $m$ such that $a_m>b_m$, and $a_k=b_k$ for all $k < m$.
- Similar for $a < b$.
- Let $a=b$ if $a_k=b_k$ for all $k$.

Then what I want to show is that

$$
a > b \quad\implies\quad f(a,n) > f(b,n) \qquad\text{for all }n \leqslant m\tag3
$$
where $m$ is the smallest index such that $a_m\neq b_m$.

For example, take the sequence $p=\{+1,-1,-1,-1,-1,\dots\}$, then

$$
f(p,1) > f(-p,1)
$$
but there are no sequences between $-p$ and $p$, so the image of $f(\cdot,1)$ lacks the interval $(f(-p,1),f(p,1)) \tag{3a}$.

---

To show $(3)$, let $a>b$ be two sequences, and let $m$ be the smallest index such that $a_m\neq b_m$.  As the sequences coincide for all indexes smaller than $m$, it's enought to show that

$$
f(a,m) = (1+2^{-m})\prod_{m+1}^\infty (1+a_k2^{-k})
 \ > \ (1-2^{-m})\prod_{m+1}^\infty (1+b_k2^{-k}) = f(b,m) \tag 4
$$
which follows from
$$
(1+2^{-m})\prod_{m+1}^\infty (1-2^{-k})
\ > \ (1-2^{-m})\prod_{m+1}^\infty (1+2^{-k})  \tag 5
$$
due to $a_k\geqslant-1$ and $b_k\leqslant1$. Rearranging $(5)$:

$$
\frac{1+2^{-m}}{1-2^{-m}}
 \ >\  \prod_{m+1}^\infty \frac{1+2^{-k}}{1-2^{-k}} \tag 6
$$
Numerical evidence proposes that $(6)$ actually holds, bit I am stuck here.

### Questions:

1. How to show inequality $(3)\,$?
2. Provided $(3)$ holds, how to show that there are always values $x$ near $1$ which cannot be represended by means of products of form $(1)\,$? Maybe it's even simpler, and $(3)$ is not needed at all.

---

- Interactive [Desmos plot of $(x(a), f(a))$](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/lafqmrcmi9)

---

### Edit

Below is a graphic that shows a plot of $f(a,1)$ for all $2^{15}$ sequences $a$, where the expansion was stopped after $a_{15}$.

The $x$-coordinates for the plot are $x(a)$, where

$$\begin{align}
x: \{\pm1\}^{\Bbb N} &\to [0,1] \\
a &\mapsto \sum_{k=1}^\infty (1+a_k) \cdot 2^{-k-1}
\end{align}$$
i.e. interpret $a$ as a real numer in binary representation with bits

$$
0.d_1 d_2 d_3\cdots
$$
where the bits are $d_k = (1+a_k)/2\in\{0,1\}$. Notice that $a>b ~\Rightarrow~ x(a)\geqslant x(b).$

Notice that $x(p)=x(-p)=0.5$ with $p$ from $(3\mathrm{a})$, but the graph below has a jump at $0.5$.  There are less pronounced jumps at 0.75 and 0.25 as well; presumable the graph is a self-similar and discontinuous.

The jumps mean that the image of $f$ has holes.

[original graphic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kxm2.png)

[image: Graph of f(a,1) up to 15 bits]

Comment: Why must there be no sequences between $p$ and $-p$?

Comment: We know there are "holes". If the first sign is $+$, than the product cannot drop below $0.2887×3=0.8661$. If the first sign is $-$, then the product cannot recover above $2.385/3=0.795$. Thus there can be no representations between $0.795$ and $0.8661$, which corresponds to the biggest hole in the plot. But the question as I understand it is are there holes arbitrarily close to $1$?

Comment: @OscarLanzi I think then, we can just continue that idea and say the next whole is between $\{-1,1,-1,-1,-1,\dots \}$ and $\{-1,-1,1,1,\dots \}$, so then this can continue on forever by just appending $-1$ to the front.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking the same thing. There seem to be no continuous intervals of allowed values everywhere. [Cantor calling, maybe?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I will answer $(1).$ Note that:
$$\dfrac{1+x+y}{1-x-y} - \dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\cdot\dfrac{1+y}{1-y} = \dfrac{2xy(x+y)}{(1-x-y)(1-x)(1-y)}>0$$
as long as we have $0<x,y<1.$ So you can just use this iteratively to the decomposition:
$x = \frac x2 + \frac x4 + \dots $ to get the more general inequality:
$$\dfrac{1+x}{1-x} > \prod_{n=1}^\infty\dfrac{1+2^{-n}x}{1-2^{-n}x}.$$
Your particular case corresponds to $x = 2^{-m}.$

For $(2),$ I am curious - you said you found the algorithm was incorrect. So what was your numerical evidence ?

Comment: Thanks.  I added a plot to the question  that shows that the graph of $f$ has holes, but the algorithm relies on each number has a representation as such a product.

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts And that assumption by the algorithm is wrong, at least for some intervals not including $1$. See my comment to the question.